# Tikz: use coordinates returned from macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

How to use a coordinate returned from a macro, for instance, with shift? See the following MWE. I tried changing where the involved delimiters are defined (inside or outside the macro), but I always obtained errors.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\newcommand{\coordsToVec}[3]{(${e#1}*(e1)+{e#2}*(e2)+{e#3}*(e3)$)}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{60}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
      \coordinate (e1) at (1,0,0);
      \coordinate (e2) at (0,1,0);
      \coordinate (e3) at (0,0,1);
      \begin{scope}[shift={(${1}*(e1)+{0}*(e2)+{0}*(e3)$)}] % WORKS
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}[shift={\coordsToVec{1}{0}{0}}] % DOES NOT WORK
      \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the `shift to vec` style with 3 arguments:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\tikzset{
  shift to vec/.style n args={3}{
    shift={(${#1}*(e1)+{#2}*(e2)+{#3}*(e3)$)},
  },
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{60}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
      \coordinate (e1) at (1,0,0);
      \coordinate (e2) at (0,1,0);
      \coordinate (e3) at (0,0,1);
      \begin{scope}[shift={(${1}*(e1)+{0}*(e2)+{0}*(e3)$)}] % WORKS
      \end{scope}
      \begin{scope}[shift to vec={1}{0}{0}] % WORKS
      \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if it would be possible to have a solution that could be used for the purpose asked in the question (with shift), but also for other uses like in a path with \draw (0,0,0) -- \coordsToVec{1}{0}{0}?

Comment: @Kevlar `\draw (0,0,0) to ([shift to vec={1}{0}{0}]0,0);`

Comment: @Kevlar You can't easily modify the parser used by TikZ.

Comment: Makes sense, I just asked out of curiosity, your original answer works perfectly for what I need.